# how to remove selected state from an edittext when an activity launches in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I have an activity that has an edittext in it, when the activity launches the edit text automatically is given a selected state and the keyboard appears immediately, the problem here is when this happens other parts of the activity the user sees become hidden, what I would like is that when the activity starts there is no focus on the edittext so that user can  view other elements on the page and then decide if they would like to select the edittext and launch the keyboard, any help would go a long way thanks!

Comment: Please google or search in SO before asking

Comment: I have but I havent found anything that works

Comment: Look at the link I postet as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in your manifest.xml file as

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

hope this help

Comment: thanks man i know about android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" but don't know how to use this. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you actually have to go into the manifest file and place `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in the activity tag for the activity you dont want the keyboard to automatically show up on, took some extensive searching but found it!